# AttributeError: 'Obstacle' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to draw obstacle on screen but got an error in return and now im stuck :/

Here is my obstacle class :

```
class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,type):
        super().__init__()
        if type == 'fly':
            self.snail_1 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\snail1.png").convert_alpha()
            self.snail_2 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\snail2.png").convert_alpha()
            self.snail_frames = [self.snail_1,self.snail_2]
            self.snail_index = 0
        else:
            self.fly_1 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\fly1.png").convert_alpha()
            self.fly_2 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\fly2.png").convert_alpha()
            self.fly_frames = [self.fly_1, self.fly_2]
            self.fly_index = 0
            self.rect = self.fly_1.get_rect(midbottom = (200,210))
```

Here is sprite.Group:

```
obstacle_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
obstacle_group.add(Obstacle('fly'))
```

and here is my method to draw:

```
obstacle_group.draw(screen)
```

What i'm doing wrong here ?

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Users\Marcin\PycharmProjects\tutorial\main.py", line 105, in <module>
>    obstacle_group.draw(screen)
>  File "C:\Users\Marcin\PycharmProjects\tutorial\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 552, in draw
>   zip(sprites, surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites))
>  File "C:\Users\Marcin\PycharmProjects\tutorial\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 552, in <genexpr>
>   zip(sprites, surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites))
> AttributeError: 'Obstacle' object has no attribute 'image'
> ```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: your `Obstacle` object needs an `image` attribute, you haven't added one to it, `draw` method for `pygame.sprite.Group` requires that sprites have that attribute along with a `rect` attribute

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) is a method which is provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`. It uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects — you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Therefore the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` must have an `image` and a `rect` attribute which can be used to draw the object. e.g.:

```py
class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,type):
        super().__init__()
        if type == 'fly':
            self.snail_1 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\snail1.png").convert_alpha()
            self.snail_2 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\snail2.png").convert_alpha()
            self.snail_frames = [self.snail_1,self.snail_2]
            self.snail_index = 0
            self.image = self.snail_1
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (200,210))
        else:
            self.fly_1 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\fly1.png").convert_alpha()
            self.fly_2 = pygame.image.load("graphics\\fly2.png").convert_alpha()
            self.fly_frames = [self.fly_1, self.fly_2]
            self.fly_index = 0
            slef.image = self.fly_1
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom = (200,210))
```